# How to animate the opening and closing of accordion items

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations, scrollview, accordion

I have implemented an accordion system on my page that functions similarly to other accordion components. When an accordion item is clicked, it opens, and when another item is clicked, the previous one closes. The unique aspect of my accordion component is that when an item is opened, it always remains positioned below the sticky top header. Currently, the functionality works correctly, but I would like to add animation to the opening and closing of the accordion items. Additionally, I have anchor tags that, when clicked, scroll to the respective accordion item and open it up. I tried using `accContent.style.maxHeight` but that creates issues with maintaining the proper positioning of the accordion items and the animation .

I would greatly appreciate your assistance in resolving these issues and achieving the desired effect of animating the accordion items while ensuring they always remain below the sticky header.

Thank you.

```js
  // Get the height of the sticky nav bar
  const stickyNavHeight = 80; // Height of the sticky navigation

  // Get all accordion elements
  const accordions = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion');

  // Loop through each accordion
  accordions.forEach(accordion => {
    const accordionItems = accordion.querySelectorAll('.accordion__item');

    // Add click event listener to each accordion item
    accordionItems.forEach(item => {
      const button = item.querySelector('.accordion__button');
      const content = item.querySelector('.accordion__content');

      button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        // Check if the clicked item is already open
        const isOpen = button.classList.contains('accordion__button--is-open');

        // Close all accordion items within the current accordion
        accordionItems.forEach(accItem => {
          const accButton = accItem.querySelector('.accordion__button');
          const accContent = accItem.querySelector('.accordion__content');

          accButton.classList.remove('accordion__button--is-open');
          accContent.style.display = 'none';
        });

        // Open the clicked item if it was closed
        if (!isOpen) {
          button.classList.add('accordion__button--is-open');
          content.style.display = 'block';

          // Calculate position of the accordion item
          const rect = item.getBoundingClientRect();
          const scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
          const position = rect.top + scrollTop;

          // Scroll below the sticky nav bar
          window.scrollTo({
            top: position - stickyNavHeight,
            behavior: 'smooth'
          });
        }
      });
    });
  });

  // Get all anchor tags with the class 'js-accordion-open'
  const anchorLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.js-accordion-open');

  // Add click event listener to each anchor tag
  anchorLinks.forEach(link => {
    link.addEventListener('click', event => {
      event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default anchor tag behavior

      const targetId = link.getAttribute('href'); // Get the target accordion item ID

      // Find the corresponding accordion item based on the target ID
      const targetAccordionItem = document.querySelector(targetId);

      if (targetAccordionItem) {
        const accordion = targetAccordionItem.closest('.accordion');
        const accordionItems = accordion.querySelectorAll('.accordion__item');

        // Close all accordion items within the current accordion
        accordionItems.forEach(accItem => {
          const accButton = accItem.querySelector('.accordion__button');
          const accContent = accItem.querySelector('.accordion__content');

          if (accItem === targetAccordionItem) {
            // Open the target accordion item
            accButton.classList.add('accordion__button--is-open');
            accContent.style.display = 'block';
          } else {
            // Close other accordion items
            accButton.classList.remove('accordion__button--is-open');
            accContent.style.display = 'none';
          }
        });

        // Calculate position of the target accordion item
        const rect = targetAccordionItem.getBoundingClientRect();
        const scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        const position = rect.top + scrollTop;

        // Scroll below the sticky nav bar
        window.scrollTo({
          top: position - stickyNavHeight,
          behavior: 'smooth'
        });
      }
    });
  });

  // Find the default accordion item and open it
  const defaultButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion__button--is-open');
  defaultButtons.forEach(defaultButton => {
    const defaultItem = defaultButton.closest('.accordion__item');
    const defaultContent = defaultItem.querySelector('.accordion__content');

    defaultContent.style.display = 'block';
  });
```

```css
header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background: darkblue;
    z-index: 1;
}

.card {
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.accordion {
        width: 650px;
    margin-bottom: 224px;
    border-top: solid 4px #000;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.accordion__item {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.accordion__button {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 20px 0 20px 16px;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: none;
    height: auto;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    transition: .4s;
    background: none;
}
.accordion__title {
    flex: 1;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
.accordion__icon {
    position: relative;
    flex: none;
    transform: rotate(0);
    width: 48px;
    height: 24px;
    transition: transform 380ms;
}
.accordion__icon::before, .accordion__icon::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #222;
    width: 18px;
    height: 4px;
}
.accordion__icon::after {
    transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform-origin: top left;
}
.accordion__body {
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 1.2s ease-out;
}
.accordion__content {
    display: none;
    margin: 16px;
}

.accordion__button--is-open {
  border-bottom: none;
  background: grey !important;
}

.accordion__button--is-open .accordion__icon {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  transition: transform 380ms;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <nav></nav>
</header>

<div class="card">
    <ul class="list">
        <li class="list__item">
            <a href="#acc1" class="js-accordion-open">Accordion item 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="list__item">
            <a href="#acc2" class="js-accordion-open">Accordion item 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="list__item">
            <a href="#acc3" class="js-accordion-open">Accordion item 3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="list__item">
            <a href="#acc4" class="js-accordion-open">Accordion item 4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="accordion">
    <div class="accordion__item" id="acc1">
        <button class="accordion__button accordion__button--is-open">
            <span class="accordion__title">Accordion item 1</span>
            <span class="accordion__icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="accordion__body">
            <div class="accordion__content">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore magni, nostrum debitis deserunt minima laborum molestiae? Fuga omnis excepturi dolor a veniam rerum. Corporis tempora a debitis provident. Quia, sed.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore magni, nostrum debitis deserunt minima laborum molestiae? Fuga omnis excepturi dolor a veniam rerum. Corporis tempora a debitis provident. Quia, sed.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore magni, nostrum debitis deserunt minima laborum molestiae? Fuga omnis excepturi dolor a veniam rerum. Corporis tempora a debitis provident. Quia, sed.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore magni, nostrum debitis deserunt minima laborum molestiae? Fuga omnis excepturi dolor a veniam rerum. Corporis tempora a debitis provident. Quia, sed.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore magni, nostrum debitis deserunt minima laborum molestiae? Fuga omnis excepturi dolor a veniam rerum. Corporis tempora a debitis provident. Quia, sed.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion__item" id="acc2">
        <button class="accordion__button">
            <span class="accordion__title">Accordion item 2</span>
            <span class="accordion__icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="accordion__body">
            <div class="accordion__content">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore magni, nostrum debitis deserunt minima laborum molestiae? Fuga omnis excepturi dolor a veniam rerum. Corporis tempora a debitis provident. Quia, sed.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion__item" id="acc3">
        <button class="accordion__button">
            <span class="accordion__title">Accordion item 3</span>
            <span class="accordion__icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="accordion__body">
            <div class="accordion__content">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore magni, nostrum debitis deserunt minima laborum molestiae? Fuga omnis excepturi dolor a veniam rerum. Corporis tempora a debitis provident. Quia, sed.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion__item" id="acc4">
        <button class="accordion__button">
            <span class="accordion__title">Accordion item 4</span>
            <span class="accordion__icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="accordion__body">
            <div class="accordion__content">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore magni, nostrum debitis deserunt minima laborum molestiae? Fuga omnis excepturi dolor a veniam rerum. Corporis tempora a debitis provident. Quia, sed.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```